# How do I make jsPDF accessible in my Ember app?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, jspdf

I'd like to export PDF documents using jsPDF in an Ember app, but I can't figure out how to make the library available within the app.

So far, I've installed the library using bower:

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "jspdf": "~1.2.61"
  }
}
```

...and imported it in the `ember-cli-build.js` file:

**ember-cli-build.js**

```
...
app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js');
...
```

However, when I try to use it (by calling `var doc = new jsPDF()` in an Ember action), I get this:

```
ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your bower compoent here :

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
....
  app.import(app.bowerDirectory + '/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js'); // Your file
....
};
```

Try to change your code to :

```
  actions:{
      createPDF: function() {

       var doc = new jsPDF(); // This part is your mistake 
       doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
       doc.save('Test.pdf');

     }
}
```

call your action for your button like

```
<button type="button" {{action "createPDF"}}>Create PDF</button>
```

and then Stop your Ember serve then again start it

```
Ember serve
```

that will work. when you add something to ember-cli-build.js you must stop and start your serve again .

Also for more information read this document : https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake (in copying my code to the question, not the code itself, which referenced the library as you suggest), but it's not actually the problem.

Comment: what is your ember version ?

Comment: @MrTheWalrus simply stop your Ember serve and Start it again , check my answer again, It will work

Comment: Yep. The missing step was 'restart the ember server'. *facepalm* Thanks for the help.